# How to loop through xml nodes in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

I have a requirement to split an xml document into multiple nodes; and then split each node separately into more sub nodes. I am using xpathSApply/getNodeSet functions in XML package. But it seems like once the xml document is split as nodes, each node is now considered as class "internal node" and hence cannot perform spath operations on it unless we save it as an xml using saveXML(). Any ideas on how this can be worked out without having to do a SAVEXML?
For example, consider sample xml below:

```
<array>
<ResidentialProperty>
    <Listing>
      <StreetAddress>
        <StreetNumber>11111</StreetNumber>
        <StreetName>111th</StreetName>
        <StreetSuffix>Avenue Ct</StreetSuffix>
        <StateOrProvince>WA</StateOrProvince>
      </StreetAddress>
      <MLSInformation>
        <ListingStatus Status="Active"/>
        <StatusChangeDate>2015-07-05T23:48:53.410</StatusChangeDate>
      </MLSInformation>
      <GeographicData>
        <Latitude>11.111111</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-111.111111</Longitude>
        <County>Pierce</County>
      </GeographicData>
</ResidentialProperty>
<ResidentialProperty>
    <Listing>
      <StreetAddress>
        <StreetNumber>11211</StreetNumber>
        <StreetName>11111334th</StreetName>
        <StreetSuffix>Av1enue Ct</StreetSuffix>
        <StateOrProvince>WA</StateOrProvince>
      </StreetAddress>
      <MLSInformation>
        <ListingStatus Status="Active"/>
        <StatusChangeDate>2017-07-05T23:48:53.410</StatusChangeDate>
      </MLSInformation>
      <GeographicData>
        <Latitude>11.111111</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-111.111111</Longitude>
        <County>Pie2rce</County>
      </GeographicData>
</ResidentialProperty>
</array>
```

I am intending to split the above into:
1. Two separate nodes with root ResidentialProperty
2. Then be able to perform XPATH operations on each of these nodes.

P.S: This is sample data and not similar to the actual data set I am working with. Just tried to use this to explain the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Please define what the final output should be. R objects containing specific nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I think I've misunderstood the question. New approach.

We use `xpathApply`, `toString.XMLNode` and `xmlParseString` to extract specific nodes in 2 objects.

Parse the XML file and exctract the nodes :

```
library(XML) :
doc=xmlParse("pathtoyourXML.xml")
result1=xmlParseString(toString.XMLNode(xpathApply(doc,"(//ResidentialProperty)[1]")))
result2=xmlParseString(toString.XMLNode(xpathApply(doc,"(//ResidentialProperty)[2]")))
```

We have 2 objects, we evaluate them with :

```
from.result1=xpathApply(result1,"//StreetAddress")
from.result2=xpathApply(result2,"//StreetAddress")
```

Sidenote : your XML is not valid. Listings elements are not closed.

EDIT 2 : In fact, you can use XPathApply on a previously "extracted" nodeset :

```
foo=xpathApply(doc,"(//ResidentialProperty)[2]")
xpathApply(foo[[1]],"//StreetAddress")
```

`foo` does not contain the result of the previous xpath expression (`(//ResidentialProperty)[2]`) but the whole XML nodeset.