# Extract XML child attribute based on another child attribute

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure. I am trying to extract the attributes StartDate and EndDate of the relationship period, that is only if rr:PeriodType is RELATIONSHIP_PERIOD.

However, the nodes for "relationship" and "accounting" have exactly the same name and am not sure how to proceed.

```
        <rr:RelationshipPeriods>
          <rr:RelationshipPeriod>
            <rr:StartDate>2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</rr:StartDate>
            <rr:EndDate>2018-12-31T00:00:00.000Z</rr:EndDate>
            <rr:PeriodType>ACCOUNTING_PERIOD</rr:PeriodType>
          </rr:RelationshipPeriod>
          <rr:RelationshipPeriod>
            <rr:StartDate>2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z</rr:StartDate>
            <rr:PeriodType>RELATIONSHIP_PERIOD</rr:PeriodType>
          </rr:RelationshipPeriod>
        </rr:RelationshipPeriods>
```

I tried using this code

```
ldply(xpathApply(xmlData, '//rr:RelationshipPeriod/rr:StartDate', getChildrenStrings), rbind)
```

But doesn't work well as it's hard to understand if it is extracting accounting or relationship period.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An xpath like this should work `//*[text() = 'RELATIONSHIP_PERIOD']/preceding-sibling::*[local-name()='StartDate' or local-name()='EndDate']`

Answer (score 0):

For rr:StartDate use XPath:

```
//rr:RelationshipPeriod[rr:PeriodType='RELATIONSHIP_PERIOD']/rr:StartDate
```

But probably better to first find the correct rr:RelationshipPeriod using XPath:

```
//rr:RelationshipPeriod[rr:PeriodType='RELATIONSHIP_PERIOD']
```

[See this answer on how to reuse the result of a XPath.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412488/3710053)
But don't use `//` in front of `rr:StartDate` and `rr:EndDate`